# What's the point of returning an "Undefined Value" when re-defining "print()" function for QScriptEngine?

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

### [Background]

The default `print()` function of [`QScriptEngine`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html) prints the result to the terminal of Qt Creator IDE for debugging purpose. As a result, the output must be redirected to our texteditor if we are going to make a ECMA script interpreter ourselves.

This part of the document ["*Making Applications Scriptable*"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/scripting.html) remains untouched since Qt 4.3.

Section ["*Redefining print()*"](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/scripting.html#redefining-print):

> Qt Script provides a built-in print() function that can be useful for
>   simple debugging purposes. The built-in print() function writes to
>   standard output. You can redefine the print() function (or add your
>   own function, e.g. debug() or log()) that redirects the text to
>   somewhere else. The following code shows a custom print() that adds
>   text to a QPlainTextEdit.

So here is the suggested re-definition of `print()`:

```
QScriptValue QtPrintFunction(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
 {
     QString result;
     for (int i = 0; i < context->argumentCount(); ++i) {
         if (i > 0)
             result.append(" ");
         result.append(context->argument(i).toString());
     }

     QScriptValue calleeData = context->callee().data();
     QPlainTextEdit *edit = qobject_cast<QPlainTextEdit*>(calleeData.toQObject());
     edit->appendPlainText(result);

     return engine->undefinedValue();
 }
```

**At first, I doubted the need of returning an "Undefined Value" by `return engine->undefinedValue();`, and it looks like the role of the argument `*engine` is just to return this void value.**

So here is what I've done to change the function:

```
QScriptValue myPrintFunction(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
{
    QString result;

    for (int i = 0; i < context->argumentCount(); ++i) {
        if (i > 0)
            result.append(" ");
        result.append(context->argument(i).toString());
    }

    /*
    QScriptValue calleeData = context->callee().data();
    QPlainTextEdit *edit = qobject_cast<QPlainTextEdit*>(calleeData.toQObject());
    edit->appendPlainText(result);

    return engine->undefinedValue();
    */
    return engine->toScriptValue(result); // ---> return the result directly
}
```

which I think is more reasonable to me: returning an evaluated `QScriptValue` from script engine, and the value can later be translated to `QString` for output. This bypass the need of dynamic type cast, which could become messy especially for customized QObjects.

For both kinds of print function, here is the exposition to the script engine:

```
 QScriptEngine *engine = new QScriptEngine(this); 
 QTextEdit *input = new QTextEdit(this);
 QTextEdit *output = new QTextEdit(this);

 // Use documented print function : 
 QScriptValue fun = engine->newFunction(QtPrintFunction);
 // Use my revised print function : 
 // QScriptValue fun = engine->newFunction(myPrintFunction);
 fun.setData(engine->newQObject(output));
 engine->globalObject().setProperty("print", fun);
```

Evaluation and output:

```
QString command = input->toPlainText();
QScriptValue result = engine->evaluate(command);
output->append(result.toString());
```

---

### [Compilable Code]

(Qt version > 4 is needed)

**test.pro**

```css
QT += core gui widgets script
TARGET = Test
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        console.cpp

HEADERS  += console.h
```

**main.cpp**

```css
#include <QApplication>
#include "console.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Console w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

**console.h**

```css
#ifndef CONSOLE_H
#define CONSOLE_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QScriptEngine>

class Console : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Console();
    ~Console();

public slots:
    void runScript();

private:
    QScriptEngine *engine;
    QVBoxLayout *layout;
    QPushButton *run;
    QTextEdit *input, *output;
};

QScriptValue QtPrintFunction(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine);
QScriptValue myPrintFunction(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine);

#endif // CONSOLE_H
```

**console.cpp**

```css
#include "console.h"

Console::Console()
{
    engine = new QScriptEngine(this);
    layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
    run = new QPushButton("Run",this);
    input = new QTextEdit(this);
    output = new QTextEdit(this);

    layout->addWidget(input);
    layout->addWidget(run);
    layout->addWidget(output);

    //QScriptValue fun = engine->newFunction(QtPrintFunction);
    QScriptValue fun = engine->newFunction(myPrintFunction);
    fun.setData(engine->newQObject(output));
    engine->globalObject().setProperty("print", fun);

    connect(run, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(runScript()));
}

void Console::runScript()
{
    QString command = input->toPlainText();
    QScriptValue result = engine->evaluate(command);
    output->append(result.toString());
}

QScriptValue QtPrintFunction(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
{
    QString result;
    for (int i = 0; i < context->argumentCount(); ++i) {
        if (i > 0)
            result.append(" ");
        result.append(context->argument(i).toString());
    }

    QScriptValue calleeData = context->callee().data();
    QTextEdit *edit = qobject_cast<QTextEdit*>(calleeData.toQObject());
    edit->append(result);

    return engine->undefinedValue();
}

QScriptValue myPrintFunction(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
{
    QString result;
    for (int i = 0; i < context->argumentCount(); ++i) {
        if (i > 0)
            result.append(" ");
        result.append(context->argument(i).toString());
    }

    return engine->toScriptValue(result);
}

Console::~Console()
{

}
```

---

### [Example]

**Input 1:**

```
print(123);
```

**Output (Qt Document `QtPrintFunction()`):**

```
123
undefined
```

**Output (My version `myPrintFunction()`):**

```
123
```

---

**Input 2:**

```
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    print(i);
```

**Output (Qt Document `QtPrintFunction()` ):**

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> undefined

**Output (`myPrintFunction()`):**

> 2

---

**Input 3:**

```
print("Stack");
print("Overflow");
```

**Output (Qt Document `QtPrintFunction()` ):**

> Stack
>
> Overflow
>
> undefined

**Output (My version `myPrintFunction()`):**

> Overflow

---

### [Question]

Although `myPrintFunction` seems to work fine at first, it didn't work when there are more than two `print` called in a script, where only the last `print` will be executed.

#### [**It seems the returning of an "Undefined Value" is NECESSARY for the print function. But why???**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613481/whats-the-point-of-returning-an-undefined-value-when-re-defining-print-fu)

Comment: As a side note in brackets, QtScripts has been "done (and perhaps even obsolete?) for a while. That was the idea after QtCS in Bilbao, 2013 when I was therein.

Comment: But not Javascript. I thought `QScriptEngine` can read them both so basically I aim to focus on Javascirpt. Or maybe you are suggesting me to remove the `qtscript` tag?

Comment: I am just trying to write that you may want to switch away from using `QtScript` in the future. (By the way, this is syntax error: `QScriptEngin engine;`)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I can feel it's dying; not much information about `QtScript` can be found now. Dunno why it was created.

Comment: It was created back then as allowing easy scripting option is fun, for instance we used in a game creator IDE for game developers, but then the Qt Project deemed the new v4 engine to be the future.

Comment: How do you 'output' what has been printed using your `myPrintFunction` ? Where does the output appear? Please specify this in your question

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Thanks for the comment, I've updated the post. Both outputs are using [**`QScriptEngine::evaluate`**](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscriptengine.html#evaluate).

Comment: @lpapp I've edited the post and added a compilable project. Fell free to test it if interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that it is NECESSARY to return `undefinedValue()`, but when you do, it's the same as not returning anything. Or essentially, as if you declared the function as `void print(...)`, so to speak.

That's what the `QtPrintFunction` does -- it returns "nothing". But it does have a side effect of appending its argument to the internal data object, whenever you call it. That's why you get all of the values passed to `print` in the `output` object.

Now, when you call `engine->evaluate()` it returns the value of the **last** evaluated expression. So, with `myPrintFunction` you get the **last** value only.

So, if you were to enter the following:

```
print("Stack");
print("Overflow");
"garbage";
```

you will only get `garbage` back (pun intended), as this was the **last** evaluated expression.

But, if you were to enter this:

```
print("Stack") + '\n' +
print("Overflow");
```

you will get both values, as you expected.

Additionally, if you enter:

```
result = "";
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    result += print(i) + '\n';
```

you will also get what you expected.

Hopefully this explains why you functions behave the way they are.

However, I don't think this is what you are trying to achieve. So... moving right along.

One thing you **can** do is to define the `myPrintFunction` as follows:

```
QScriptValue myPrintFunction(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
{
    static QString result;
    for (int i = 0; i < context->argumentCount(); ++i) {
        if (i > 0)
            result.append(" ");
        result.append(context->argument(i).toString());
    }
    result.append('\n');

    return engine->toScriptValue(result);
}
```

This will "work" the way you expected it to work. The only problem is that you can't clear the value of `result`. If that works for you, then that will be that.

There is a more betterer way to do this, which is probably to define a class, eg:

```
class QTrace: public QObject
{
    ...
    void clear();
    void append(const QString& value);
    const QString& get();
}
```

and pass an object of that class to `fun.setData(engine->newQObject(trace))` and define your function as:

```
QScriptValue myPrintFunction(QScriptContext *context, QScriptEngine *engine)
{
    QString result;
    for (int i = 0; i < context->argumentCount(); ++i) {
        if (i > 0)
            result.append(" ");
        result.append(context->argument(i).toString());
    }
    result.append('\n');

    QScriptValue calleeData = context->callee().data();
    QTrace *trace = qobject_cast<QTrace*>(calleeData.toQObject());
    trace->append(result);

    return engine->undefinedValue();
}
```

Lastly, you would change your `runScript` function to something like:

```
trace->clear();

QScriptValue result = engine->evaluate(command);
if(result.isError())
    output->append(result.toString());
else
    output->append(trace->get());
```

Or there are probably other ways, but hopefully will help you get the ball rolling in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborated answer! You answer is as good as @dbcb 's though a little bit late. I wish I can split my bounty but the system doesn't allow it : ( So here is my decision: I accept your answer but I give the bounty to dbcb which answered earlier, hoping it's fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer: you don't need to return undefinedValue. You can return anything you want. However, `engine->evaluate()` can only return a single value, which I think is the source of the confusion.

Take a look at the evaluation code:

```
QString command = input->toPlainText();
QScriptValue result = engine->evaluate(command);
output->append(result.toString());
```

This takes a script string and evaluates it, assigning the resulting value into `result`, where it is then appended to the `QTextEdit` control. The return value of `evaluate()` is going to be the last value of the script. For example:

```
QString command = "var a=1, b=2; a; b;";
QScriptValue result = engine->evaluate(command);
output->append(result.toString());
```

`result` would contain 2, which would then get logged to the `QTextEdit` control.

So, what's happening? Take this input for example:

```
print("Stack");
print("Overflow");
```

When using the `QtPrintFunction`, "Stack" and "Overflow" are added to the `output` control as part of the `QtPrintFunction` implementation. When the `evaluate()` finishes, the last statement was `print("Overflow")` which returns undefined. The evaluation code then takes that return value and adds it to the `output`, resulting in:

```
Stack
Overflow
undefined
```

When using the `myPrintFunction`, that implementation doesn't log anything to the `output`, but returns the value. The result is that the `evaluate()` function only returns the last value ("Overflow"), resulting in this output:

```
Overflow
```

Which is what you are seeing.

Since you want to redirect output to your own custom text editor, you need to change this block of code:

```
QScriptEngine *engine = new QScriptEngine(this); 
 QTextEdit *input = new QTextEdit(this);
 //QTextEdit *output = new QTextEdit(this);
 YourCustomEditor *output = getYourCustomEditor();

 // Use my revised print function : 
 QScriptValue fun = engine->newFunction(myPrintFunction);
 fun.setData(engine->newQObject(output)); // pass your editor in
 engine->globalObject().setProperty("print", fun);
```

Then in `myPrintFunction` you need to send the output to `YourCustomEditor` in a way that's similar to the `QtPrintFunction`. Then you no longer need to output the result from `evaluate()`:

```
QString command = input->toPlainText();
QScriptValue result = engine->evaluate(command);
// output->append(result.toString()); <- not needed anymore
```

I've worked with embedded interpreters many times before and things can get confusing quickly. Hopefully this is clear enough to help.

Comment: Really appreciate! It's clear enough and the answer is...much simpler than I thought lol, things can really get confusing quickly.

Comment: Btw, these two sentences: `The return value of evaluate() is going to be the last value of the script.` and `When using the myPrintFunction, that implementation doesn't log anything to the output, but returns the value` totally cleared my confusion. Thanks again, and you deserved the bounty!